# Отношение Laravel как проверить?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно привязать таблицы между собой через отношения (Relasionship)? Я уже третий день не могу правильно реализовать отношение и проверить через функцию dd().

Например мне нужно из таблицы users привязать к таблице documents

1) В модели User

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function document()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Document');
    }

}
```

2) Создаю миграцию и модель Documents - Document

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class DocumentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
        Schema::dropIfExists('documents');

    }
}




namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Document extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }

}
```

3) Теперь как нужно вывести информацию о пользователе id в document то есть user_id ?

4) Насколько я понял мне нужно создать controller DocumentController?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно получить информацию о user от документа то в модели Document еще указывайте

`public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }`

потом будете как обычно пользоваться

> document->user

Comment: Еще можно указать уточнение по какому полю искать


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Document', 'user_id', 'id');
    }



вот тут еще можно посмотреть более подробно: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Answer (score 1):

в миграции user_id должен быть integer, так же можно сделать связку по полю с таблицей users.

```
Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::table('documents', function($table){

    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

создаете модель

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Doc extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'documents';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'user_id'
        ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];
}
```

создаете контроллер

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DocController extends Controller
{

    #GET
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = $request->get('user_id');

        $doc = App\Doc::select([
            'documents.id',
            'documents.title',
            'users.name as user_name', # инфо о пользователе
            ])
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'documents.user_id')
            ->where([
                ['user_id', $user_id]
            ])
            ->get();

        return view('ваш шаблон',$doc);
    }
}
```